# TTreeView: how to check/uncheck ONLY children from a TTreeNode?

Tags: delphi, treeview, vcl, treenode

Windows 10, Delphi 11.

I want to set `.Checked` only for children of a single `TTreeNode` with checkboxes. This is the default behavior in TreeViews. But the following code **also** selects all **siblings** (on the same level as the starting node). In fact, the call `Node.GetNextChild()` and `Node.GetNextSibling()` don't seem to make any difference.

```
procedure TMapIntForm.CheckAllNodes(Node: TTreeNode; Check: Boolean);
var
  AParent: TTreeNode;
begin
  AParent := Node;
  while (Node <> nil) do
  begin
    Node.Checked := Check;
    CheckAllNodes(Node.GetFirstChild(), Check);
    if Node <> TreeView.Selected then
      Node := Node.GetNextChild(Node) // .GetNextSibling()?
    else Node := nil;
  end;
end;
```

How do I check **only** children from a node on a certain level without other nodes on the **same** level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the wrong node into `GetNextChild()`. It expects a child node of a parent node on which it is called, but you are passing it the parent node itself instead.

I would suggest using a different loop to iterate the child nodes:

```
procedure TMapIntForm.CheckAllNodes(Node: TTreeNode; Check: boolean);
var
  AChild: TTreeNode;
begin
  Node.Checked := Check;
  AChild := Node.getFirstChild;
  while (AChild <> nil) do
  begin
    CheckAllNodes(AChild, Check);
    if AChild.Selected then Break;
    AChild := AChild.getNextSibling;
  end;
end;
```